# A regex to match "\.fbcdn\.net" but not match ".xyz.{0,20}\.fbcdn\.net"

Tags: regex, regex-group

**Preamble:**

I have a bunch of TLS connections in a single pcap file.  These TLS traffics are for either Instagram or for Facebook. I want to classify them in two groups using two(or more) regex patterns on the SNIs (Server Name Indication) of their TLS handshakes.

**The Question:**

The strings of SNIs are as follow:

For Instagram:

- `instagram.fsst1-2.fna.fbcdn.net`
- `instagram.acd.yc.fbcdn.net`
- `instagram.xffuyw-34.hj.fbcdn.net`

For Facebook:

- `static.xx.fbcdn.net`
- `dyna.yudhn.fbcdn.net`
- `asq.iud.fbcdn.net`

As you see above, both groups have `fbcdn.net` inside of their SNIs. The obvious difference between the groups is that Instagram's SNIs have `instagram` in their SNIs.

Which patterns can I have to classify this streams?

*Note that I must have `fbcdn` in both patterns to avoid mismatch with other non-instagram and non-facebook pattherns.*

**Failed-tries So Far**

Instagram:

`/instagram.{1,20}\.fbcdn\.net/s`

Facebook

`/[^instagram.{1,20}]\.fbcdn\.net/s`

The facebook pattern above doesn't match facebook's streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^instagram.{1,20}]` is a negated character class. It doesn't do what you think it is doing. Inside a character class there is no grouping or quantifier. Every character is a single literal character inside and if first character is `^` then it matches any character that is not one of the characters used inside the character class. For this example it matches a character that is not in this list: `i,n,s,t,a,g,r,a,m,.,{,1,2,0,}` (comma is not included)

For your need, you can use a negative lookahead here:

```
^(?!instagram\.).{1,20}\.fbcdn\.net$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vm7B5m/2)

`(?!instagram\.)` is negative lookahead assertion after line start anchor. This will skip all lines that are starting with `instagram.`

[Read more about lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

Without lookahead support you can use a long regex using negated character classes:

```
^(?:[^i]|i[^n]|in[^s]|ins[^t]|inst[^a]|insta[^g]|instag[^r]|instagr[^a]|instagra[^m]|instagram[^.]).{1,30}\.fbcdn\.net$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Vm7B5m/3)

Comment: I'm trying to use this pattern for [HyperScan](https://01.org/hyperscan), but it returns **Zero-width assertions are not supported**. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Hmm without lookahead assertion it will be quite clumsy regex, let me think over it.

Comment: check my updated regex that works without lookahead support.

Comment: Thank you for your second pattern. But I think it is not correct for cases that the `instagram` word is not at the start of the string's lines.( even if I remove the `^` character). Am I right?

Comment: The `SNI` inside of a TCP stream does appears in the middle of packet and not at the beginning. So I guess I must looking for another way (if any). Right?

Comment: Ok try replacing `^` and `$` with Word boundary `\b`